# moving an img with touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to drag the bucket image (left and right only) with touch.
I'm new to mobile developing so I'm not that acquainted with touch events.

```
    bucket = document.getElementById("bucket");
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var startx = 0;
        var dist = 0;

        bucket.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
            var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]; // reference first touch point (ie: first finger)
            startx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX); // get x position of touch point relative to left edge of browser
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false)

        bucket.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
            var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]; // reference first touch point for this event
            var dist = parseInt(touchobj.clientX) - startx;
            bucket.style.left = bucket.offsetLeft + dist;
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false)
    }, false)
```

Thank you all the helpers.

Comment: Maybe this'll help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29705279/3168107.

Comment: hope this helps you  .. https://mobiforge.com/design-development/touch-friendly-drag-and-drop